# Elastic beanstalk EC2 instances don't require pem certificate on ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an aws application using Elastic Beanstalk, in "Configure service access" I configured a EC2 key pair as you can see below:

[ec2 key par config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vivZ8.png)

When I ssh to the EC2 instances I'm able to get in **without using the cert**. I can't find a way to make the use of the certificate **mandatory**.

I did some research on the instances that Elastic Beanstalk created, the cert is correctly configured but `PubkeyAuthentication` is disabled, it looks like this:

`# PubkeyAuthentication yes`

I could remove the comment from PubkeyAuthentication this way it should be always required, but I'd have to apply same changes every-time a new instance is created.

Currently I'm only blocking access by IP since I removed from the security group inbound connections from 0.0.0.0/0 on port 22 (ssh), and allowed access from my IP on port 22. what I want to also protect ssh connection with the cert configured.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the key was used, because it was on my key chain.

I found that by running the ssh command with "-v" and found the RSA SHA256 of the key used:

```
debug1: Offering public key:  RSA SHA256:oRWr...A agent
debug1: Server accepts key:  RSA SHA256:oRWr...LA agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

Then run ssh-add -l and found the key in there:

```
2048 SHA256:oRWr...LA  (RSA)
```